# Why did pressing dot after an object in Eclipse stop showing list of methods popup?

Tags: java, php, eclipse

Is there something wrong with my Eclipse?

I use Eclipse every day. If I press dot after an object then a list of its methods will popup.

This was working a few hours ago, but suddenly stopped working, and now it shows nothing.

This only happens in some blocks of code, other blocks of code seem to work fine.

```
if(actionType.equals("get triples")){
     // the code here has no problem
}
else if(actionType.equals("get payment url")){
     // the code inside this block has the problem
}
```

I compiled & ran my application in eclipse, and the app runs ok, there's no problem.

I don't want to reinstall JDK because I need to do a lot of setup & that costs lots of time.

I also tried doing "Project--> Clean" but it didn't fix anything.

So how to fix it?

Comment: Does it show anything when you put your cursor behind the dot and press `Ctrl` + `LShift` + `Space`?

Comment: ex, i keyed in "object." ---> Occurrence of 'object'

Comment: Do you have the same issue when you create a new project that simply says "Hello world"?

Comment: seem thgis only happened in some certain block of code, other block of code has no problem

Comment: That was what I was figuring. Can you edit your post to show what block causes this? Chances are you're just trying to type something that can't be placed there. Intellisense doesn't work for wrong code

Comment: done, probally I missed some backets?

Comment: but it showed no error so not sure

Comment: I assume you've already tried restarting Eclipse? If yes: I have no idea what could cause it that you haven't tried already.

Comment: yes i tried. I even restarted the whole PC, but nothing happened

Comment: now suddenly everything is ok. Properly eclipse still remember the old error or sthing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about Java, that's controlled by the Auto Activation trigger preference:

[image: Java's Content Assist preference page]

That it didn't trigger in that specific location might have been a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found the way to fix it for me was even though my Auto Activation was on I had to go into Advanced under Content assist and check off all the boxes in the two groups to get it to work so I could say myFrame. and see all the methods and such come up as I type.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both suggestions above and didn't fix the issue until I clicked on the "Restore Defaults" button on the Content Assist->Advanced page.  I don't I have ever come to this page before so not sure how it got modified from the default.